# Python - Unable to use pip and probably for the same reason unable to use library python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, pip, urllib3, python-telegram-bot

I have a rather bizarre problem that I havent been able to get around despite spending quite sometime Googling.

**First** when I wanna search or install a package using **pip** in a virtualenv I get this:

```
~$ ./virenv/bin/pip search telegram

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee3a528e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /pypi
...
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee3a4ca2d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /pypi


Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "~/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
...
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fee3a4ca390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))
```

I'm not behind a proxy and I'm able to run

```
sudo -H pip search telegram
```

and it works seemlessly. 
My pip version:

```
~$ ./virenv/bin/pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from ~/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

I examine patches folks had [here](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/commit/1c30a1f3a4af9591f480a338f75221bdf5ca48da?diff=split) but the lines are already present in my pip's packages. Also replace

*~/Test/virenvTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py*
with the one [here](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/connection.py#L205) (since it seems to include additional lines) to no avail. And the modification to

*python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py*

mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1805) (by alexandrem) doesnt seem possible since the line has a different logic.

I know I was just groping around :(

**Second** (another symptom) within Pycharm I can install packages and run the code without problem. But again when I try to run this [script](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinebot.py) (that needs going to the Internet) from command line

```
$ ~/virenv/bin/python ~/PycharmProjects/bot/test1.py

2017-12-04 16:59:30,278 - telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool - WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa159cd1650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/setWebhook
...
2017-12-04 16:59:30,280 - telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connectionpool - WARNING - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa159cd18d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))': /botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/setWebhook
2017-12-04 16:59:30,280 - telegram.ext.updater - ERROR - error in bootstrap phase; try=0 max_retries=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 196, in _request_wrapper
raise NetworkError('urllib3 HTTPError {0}'.format(error))
...
NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/setWebhook (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa159cd1990>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))
2017-12-04 16:59:30,300 - telegram.ext.updater - ERROR - unhandled exception
...
NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/setWebhook (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa159cd1990>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))


2017-12-04 16:59:31,282 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - CRITICAL - stopping due to exception in another thread
```

It seems there's something wrong on both situations(I'm not sure since I'm a mediocre on the field) maybe it is python ***urllib3*** package but how should I fix it? Any help please!

Comment: What does `curl https://pypi.python.org` say?

Comment: @hoefling Tnx for your attention, but that particular machine is not in my vicinity now. I guess apart from `pip` and `python-telegram-bot` everything went fine. And just for the record I found out that after I ran a [vpn](https://getlantern.org) they would work well. I dont know what was wrong that after disconnecting the vpn they still try to go through it!